# Shape of curved spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, curvature

Can the shape of curved space time under influence of mass be closely modelled by any function?

Like, without getting into tensors and Euclidean/non-euclidean geometry, can I make a function (in one dimension), something of the form $y=ax^n+...$ to closely tell the curvature of space time?

Comment: Other than something like $R^{abcd}R_{abcd}$?

Comment: The Kretschmann scalar for a Schwarzschild metric has a simple $1/r^6$ dependence.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing I'm aware of is [Flamm's paraboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric#Flamm%27s_paraboloid), which is an embedding of the curvature of the *spatial* part of the Schwarzschild metric in an ambient 3D Euclidean space.

However, it should be noted that this only accounts for a 2D spatial slice of Schwarzschild;  in effect, it only tells you about the curvature of space, not the curvature of spacetime.  In particular, the geodesics on Flamm's paraboloid (the paths followed by freefalling objects) are *not* the paths that would be followed by real objects in Schwarzschild spacetime, since real objects are moving in time as well as in space.